# Need to return "Y" or "N" based on results from another cell

Tags: excel-formula

I'm sure this is not as hard as I am making it but I am really stuck.  I need "Y" or "N" as the result in the "current?" cell.  The "CPR Certified Date" cell will be manually entered.  The "CPR Cert Expires" cell has the following function to give it a date 2 years after the "CPR Certified Date" =IF([@[CPR Certified Date]]="","",DATE(YEAR([@[CPR Certified Date]]) + 2, MONTH([@[CPR Certified Date]]), DAY([@[CPR Certified Date]])))  the problem is that it was returning a 1901 date if the Certified date was blank.

For some reason when I added the IF to this to make it not return a 1901 date when the Certified date was blank, it made my Current field change to "Y".  This is the function I currently have in the Current cell
=IF([@[CPR Cert Expires]]>$K$1,"Y","N")  K1 by the way contains =TODAY() to determine whether the expiration date has passed or not.

Have I made this too complicated?  Or am I in a fog?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOAfE.png)

Comment: Try using EDATE function (24 months equals 1 year)

Comment: Would be nice if you provide some `.xls` to reproduce the issue. Also, this https://superuser.com/tags/microsoft-excel StackExchange area could be a more suitable place for such qustion.

Comment: My issue isn't with the dates.  It's with the Y/N results and I believe it's because that formula is picking up the formula in the Expires cell.

Comment: If that's the only problem, then add the same solution to that "current"-function: `IF([@[CPR Certified Date]]="","",IF([@[CPR Cert Expires]]>$K$1,"Y","N"))`

Comment: Your 1st formula can be reduced to this: `=IF([@[CPR Certified Date]]="","",EDATE([@[CPR Certified Date]],24))`